# Heroku poatgres replication to Rds using Bucardo

Tags: heroku, locking, amazon-rds, database-replication

i tried to set up a replication between Heroku postgres and rds via bucardo running on Ec2 instance.

I get an error when I try to add the sync , saying validation failed for herokudb

I can connect to heroku from ec2 instance and gave the user to be trusted on pg_hba.conf file.

Any thoughts or prerequisite pls.

Bucardo_source user on postures, has write and read prev.

Thanks,
Anusha

Tried with trust
Still error